# how to delete two-dimentional double array

Tags: c++, pointers, double, new-operator

I wrote two functions - one to create two-dimentional double array, and another one to delete it.

```
double** createMatrix(int n)
{
    double **a = new double *[n];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new double[n];
    return a;
}

void deleteMatrix(double** a, int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        delete [] a[i]; // ERROR HERE
    delete []a;
}
```

Allocated array is working fine. But when I try to free it, I get an error (on a marked line): "project2.exe has triggered a breakpoint.".
I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

edit:
I created a full program:

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    double **m = createMatrix(n);
    deleteMatrix(m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

And it's working fine. Also, I found my problem. It was a typo in `copyMatrix` function.

```
for (int j=0; j <= n; j++) // should be < instead of <=
    a[i][j] = originalMatrix[i][j];
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you make a small **complete** program that exhibits this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`?

Comment: That's the way to do this. There's something else, that's wrong. For example, invalid pointer `a` in `deleteMatrix`. In `deleteMatrix`, you can try to print all values to see, that something else is wrong.

Comment: I expect you have a double delete or other heap corruption and the breakpoint is being triggered when the memory deallocation detects that.

Comment: Looks okay, may be something you are doing between the create and delete is corrupting it.

Comment: Posted code is fine. The error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is not to use an array in the first place.

How to create an `n` x `n` matrix ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using Row = std::vector<int>;
using Matrix = std::vector<Row>;

int main() {
    size_t const n = 5;

    Matrix matrix(Row(n), n);
}
```

Simple right ? And as a bonus, copy, move and destruction are provided free of charge.